# Why is received mail stored in ~/Maildir and sent mail in ~/mail?

Tags: ubuntu, postfix, courier

So I setup my mail server eons, and I'm doing maintenance on it right now and I'd figure I'd fix a few things with it that's bugged me forever. Mainly, I'm trying to move all the mail storage into a single folder and make it a hidden folder.

However, I can't figure out why sent mail is being stored it `~/mail` while received mail is being stored in `~/Maildir`. Everything I read says that it's my client storing it in the mail folder, but I don't see how that's possible. What configuration file/property determines where users' sent mail is stored?

Server setup:

- Ubuntu 14.04
- Postfix
- Courier

Comment: Which mail client are you running and do you run it on the same server where postfix and courier run?

Comment: My mail client is thunderbird and it's ran locally, off server

Answer (score 1):

Your configurations of postfix and dovecot diverge.

In postfix you have the parameter [`home_mailbox`](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#home_mailbox) to configure where mail goes to. In your case it's Maildir.

For courier I did find something in their incomplete documentation: http://www.courier-mta.org/imap/README.html